# Datasheet for ON660 Philips transistor

Tags: datasheet

I have ON660 Philips transistors, and can not find any datasheet. The label on transistor is:
**PH

331XN

m9249**

The package is SOT-82.
Maybe it is the equivalent of BD334? But it would be very nice to have a Philips datasheet.

Comment: If the marking is 331XN, then my guess would be BD331. http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/123384/PHILIPS/BD331.html?

Comment: Yes, it could be, but not 100%. Or maybe I should connect 80V to CE and wait for what happens? :)